# Replace text with blank in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am looking to replace all text info if avaialble like below with blank in `notepad++`

```
/* 1 */

/* 2 */

/* 2000 */
```

Kindly guide me for possible solution.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9e6fd2523bd000017dff71"),
    "status" : "completed",
     "request_id" : ObjectId("5d9e6fd2523bd000017dff70")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9e769d523bd000017dff73"),
    "status" : "completed",
    "request_id" : ObjectId("5d9e769d523bd000017dff72")
}

/* 3 */
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to target are old style C comments occurring on a single line, try:

```
Find:    /\*.*?\*/
Replace: (empty)
```

To cover comments spanning across lines, you may use the above with DOT ALL mode enabled in Notepad++.  Or, you could just use the following pattern in any mode:

```
/\*[\s\S]*?\*/
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you. If try to find using /\*.*?\*/ it finding nothing. How to enable DOT ALL mode?

Comment: The find/replace dialog should have an option for dot all, perhaps mentioning dot matching across newlines.  If you can't figure it out, just use the second option `/\*[\s\S]*?\*/`

Comment: Second option is also saying '0 occurances were replaced'. It's not finding any text.

Comment: @user11899725 Then perhaps you are not even doing this find/replace in regex mode?  My solution is working in the demo, q.v. my updated answer.